# Extract text from pdf/doc/docx file using AWS Lambda (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, parsing, text, lambda, extract

I'm trying to extract text from doc/docx/pdf file in an AWS Lambda function written in Node.js.
I need to extract text data as an array of words. I've tried using a few different npm packages, but I've noticed that it just skipping those functions.

AWS Lambda Function:

```
import { PDFExtract } from "pdf.js-extract";

...

export const handler = async (event) => {

    ...

    const pdfExtract = new PDFExtract();
    const tempFilePath = join(tmpdir(), "resume.pdf");
    const buffer = readFileSync(tempFilePath);
    const wordsList = [];

    await pdfExtract.extractBuffer(buffer, {}, (err, data) => {
        if (err)
            return console.log(err);
        data.pages[0].content.forEach((e) => {
            const str = e.str.trim().split(" ");
            str.forEach((word) => {
                if (word.length > 1)
                    wordsList.push(word);
            });
        });
    });
        console.log(wordsList);
}
```

[files structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU8eA.png)

The same code works perfectly fine on my local machine, but when I deploy it to AWS Lambda, it fails to extract any text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda function gets the file as a base64 string. I was finally able to figure out what the problem was and it was the timeout setting but despite that, I using now Python instead of Node.js and it works much faster. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried similar thing in python, which works for me . How are you deploying your code to lambda? I am assuming your node packages are deployed properly and when you test your lambda function , it runs , just doesn't return text. if that's not the case, please include it in the question. also, what kind of pdf are you using , text based pdf or image based pdf?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to parse pdf files that are text-based (resume files).
I've tried anything but it still returns an error or sometimes null without entering the extract function.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf.js-extract

Comment: @YinonOzery - if it works in your local machine, how does your lambda reads the pdf, in other words how are you passing pdf to your lambda function? is it in a s3 bucket??

Comment: I have a similar issue. It's working locally im my testcase, but I'm not able to get it working within lambda environment (using sam cli and docker). Parsing fails without any error message. I figured out, that it seems to realate to missing 'canvas' node-module since it uses native libs. But I've no idea how to provide it to my lambda.